# StackOverflowException with Common.Logging and Common.Logging.Simple.CommonLoggingTraceListener

Tags: trace, stack-overflow, common.logging

I'm trying to redirect all log messages from `System.Diagnostics.Trace` to `Common.Logging` [as documented on the Common.Logging website](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/2.0.0/reference/html/ch01.html#d4e330).

Unfortunately when I run my application I get a `StackOverflowException` and I'm not sure why. If I delete the `<system.diagnostics>` section it runs fine.

I've replicated this problem using a simple Console application which makes a single call to `Trace.WriteLine("hello");`

Here's my complete `App.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <clear />
        <add name="commonLoggingListener"
             type="Common.Logging.Simple.CommonLoggingTraceListener, Common.Logging"
             initializeData="LogLevel=Trace" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

**Can anyone make any suggestions as to what is causing the `StackOverflowException`?**

Comment: I'm sure that you've figured this out by now but I don't see any answers. One of the most common causes for a StackOverflowException is if you are making use of the Trace listener for Common Logging. It would make sense that if you redirect all of .Diag'ics.Trace to Common.Logging that you could end up with a overflow depending on which logging factory adapter you've configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved on from this issue now, but I think the answer from CodeMonkeyKing is probably accurate:

> I'm sure that you've figured this out by now but I don't see any
>   answers. One of the most common causes for a StackOverflowException is
>   if you are making use of the Trace listener for Common Logging. It
>   would make sense that if you redirect all of .Diag'ics.Trace to
>   Common.Logging that you could end up with a overflow depending on
>   which logging factory adapter you've configured.